# What is the correct Regex for this?

Tags: c#, regex, token

I have a text like this:

```
(0.2 furry
  (0.81 fast
    (0.3)
    (0.2)
  )
  (0.1 fishy
    (0.3 freshwater
      (0.01)
      (0.01)
    )
    (0.1)
  )
)
```

I want to split it using `Regex.Split`. The format I want the string[] to be is:

`(
0.2
furry
(
0.81
fast
(
0.3
)
(
0.2
)
)
(
...` (you get the point)

I'm using the Regex expression `([()\\s])`, but this also gives me strings for the spaces. Could you please tell me the correct Regex expression?

Comment: Are you trying to split by runs of whitespace?

Comment: Look like S-expression

Comment: Are you looking to parse this input to a C# object?

Comment: @someone my delimeters are '(' , ')' and space but I don't want to keep any spaces in the split.

Comment: @aloisdg No, just the string[] that Regex.Spilt creates

Comment: @NickDelta alright then. Keep in mind that the string that you are splitting is a well defined format know as [S-Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

Comment: [Code jam?](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/186264/)

Comment: @Selvin yes haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either match (as others have answered) or split on spaces and parentheses:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9ktIeN/1)

<sub>Note that I replaced matches with `\n` for display purposes in the link above. 
You would instead split on the pattern below.</sub>

```
\s+|(?<=\()(?!\s)|(?<!\s)(?=\))
```

This pattern is composed of 3 options:

1. `\s+` match any whitespace character one or more times
2. `(?<=\()(?!\s)` Match a position that is preceded by `(` but not proceeded by whitespace (because the first option will already have matched this position)
3. `(?<!\s)(?=\))` Match a position that is not preceded by whitespace (because the first option will already have matched this position), but that is proceeded by `)`

Comment: @NickDelta TBH, this solution is performing more steps than the other that was already listed here, including a comment by @@someone. Also do you mind sharing your conclusion as to why `this is exactly what I was looking for`? Did the other answer not work for you, how'd you measure performance etc...?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ his original question was to split using `Regex.Split`. Whilst it may not be as performant as other answers, it does complete the task in the way the OP expects it to. I agree, there may be better alternatives, but this is presenting the split option whereas the other answers present the match alternative.

Comment: I agree, but you and or OP do know that `Regex.Split` under the hood ends up delegating all of it's work churning through the `Matches` anyways right and *adding them to a new List<String>*. They've wrapped it up to spit matches out in a litte array for you... To be honest it doesn't matter as long as the OP get's the results they need.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ yes, but it could be a task that was specifically assigned to OP, for all we know, the data could be inconsistent with other match formats proposed `\d+\.\d+` - e.g. negative numbers, scientific notation `e-5`, fractions `3/4` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, an expression similar to

```
[)(]|\d+\.\d+|\w+
```

might simply work OK:

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"[)(]|\d+\.\d+|\w+";
        string input = @"(0.2 furry
          (0.81 fast
            (0.3)
            (0.2)
          )
          (0.1 fishy
            (0.3 freshwater
              (0.01)
              (0.01)
            )
            (0.1)
          )
        )";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

### [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/QMLb11)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AxvdTQ/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/AxvdTQ/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I haven't tested your regex, but I believe mine (`[()]|[^\s()]+`) is simpler.

Comment: @someone yes, it's better in since of how fewer steps are done. Why not create an answer for the OP?